# Perl regex: indent/add words after matching keyword in a string?

Tags: regex, string, perl

How do I go about indenting text before and after a keyword in a string using regex?

lets say i have the following String

```
This is
some KEYWORD filler
text
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
This is
some <*>KEYWORD<*> filler
text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal interpretation would be the following:

```
s/(KEYWORD)/<*>$1<*>/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has different ways of doing things so I'm just going to add that you can also use a combination of
[**Lookahead** and **Lookbehind** Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this.

```
s/(?=KEYWORD)|(?<=KEYWORD)/<*>/g
```

Regular expression:

```
(?=            # look ahead to see if there is:
 KEYWORD       # 'KEYWORD'
)              # end of look-ahead
 |             # OR
(?<=           # look behind to see if there is:
 KEYWORD       # 'KEYWORD'
)              # end of look-behind
```

Comment: I think this is clever because you only used <*> once.

Answer (score 0):

Simpson, here a one-liner to perform your replacement using Perl regex:

```
($result = $subject) =~ s/(KEYWORD)/<*>$1<*>/mg;
```

**How does it work?**

The regex is simply `(KEYWORD)` It matches the literal string "KEYWORD" and captures it in Group 1.

In the substitution, `$1` refers to the content of Group 1.